# An equation for finding the axis of symmetry

Tags: functions

So in a lesson our teacher gave us this element:

-For proving that a function has an axis of symmetry in a given $x= x_0$ we need to prove that the function is even at that point , so we use the following equation:

$f(2x_0 - x) = f(x)$

- I want a deep explanation about this equation which can provide me a more comprehensive view about the topic.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To you remember how to shift and scale the graph of a function?

Answer (score 2):

Asserting that the line $x=x_0$ is an axis of symmetry of $f$ is the same thing as asserting that you always have $f(x_0+t)=f(x_0-t)$. But then, for each $x$, $2x_0-x=x_0-(x-x_0)$, and therefore$$f(2x_0-x)=f\bigl(x_0-(x-x_0)\bigr)=f\bigl(x_0+(x-x_0)\bigr)=f(x).$$